# Trying to delete all messages sent by a user with a certain role unless the message is !verify

Tags: discord, discord.js

I'm trying to make a verification system. Members are supposed to type !verify. If they don't type that, I want my bot to delete the sent message.

```
module.exports = {
  client.on('message', (message) => {
    if (message.member.roles.cache.has('793205873949278279')){
      if (!message.content === '!verify') {
        message.delete({ timeout: 1 });
      }
    }
  })
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*'message.member.roles'* returns an array of role **objects** the message author has.
If you'd like to find out whether the user has the corresponding role or not, you would first want to **get the role** using its ID (or name if preferred) and only then check if the user has it.

```
const role = message.guild.roles.cache.get('role id here') // Gets the role object using it's ID
if (!message.member.roles.cache.has(role)) return // The command will not be executed if the user does not have the corresponding role
```

One more thing to note: It seems like you're trying to delete the message after one millisecond - Which let's be honest is quite useless since you'll never notice the difference if it's 0 or 1 milliseconds - So my advice is to either delete it after 1000 milliseconds (1 second) if that's what you wanted to do, or not set a timeout at all.